# Unable to get the data to next page in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJS. I am currently building a small mobile store where I display the data of all the products in the front page and on clicking the product, i wanted to show the description of the product in the next page.

When I click on the product, I was able to redirect to the next page but not the contents of the page.

My index.html

```
<div class="container">
<header>
<h1>My Mobile Store</h1>
</header>
<hr class="header-seperator">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Mobile Store</a>
</div>
<div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Mobiles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fashions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Footwears</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
<div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

My app.js

```
(function() {
var storeConfig = function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    controller: 'StoreController',
    templateUrl: 'views/products-list.html',
    controllerAs: 'StreCtrl'
})
.when('/product', {
    controller: 'StoreController',
    templateUrl: 'views/product.html',
    controllerAs: 'prodCtrl'
});
};

var app= angular.module('mystore',['ngRoute']).config(storeConfig); 
app.service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var product = [];

    return {
        getProduct: function () {
            console.log(product);
            return product;
        },
        setProduct: function(value) {           
            product = value;
            //console.log(product);
        }
    };
});

app.controller('StoreController',[ '$http', 'sharedProperties',  function($http,sharedProperties) {
var store = this;
store.products = [];
store.error = "false";
store.item = [];

$http.get('data/products.json').success(function(data) {
store.products = data;
 }).error(function() {
 store.error = "true";
 });

store.showProduct = function(product) {
sharedProperties.setProduct(product);
};

store.item = sharedProperties.getProduct;
console.log("Store Item");
console.log(store.item);
}]);
})();
```

I couldn't get the data in store.item. What is the mistake I am doing. Any help will be grateful.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: please do change this line `store.item = sharedProperties.getProduct;` to `store.item = sharedProperties.getProduct();`

Comment: $http.get('data/products.json').success(function(data) {
store.products = data;   store.item = data;

Comment: @Reena : Thanks for your suggestion. Let me also try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a method reference to your scope object, Instead of you need to call method.

Change From

```
store.item = sharedProperties.getProduct;
```

TO

```
store.item = sharedProperties.getProduct();
```